# Does it make sense checking for equality on XF BindablePropery?

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Does this make sense, or the equality check is redundant?

```
public int SelectedIndex
{
  get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
  set
  {
    if (value != SelectedIndex)
      SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value);
  }
}
```

I looked a bit into the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs), and it looks like the object is going a long way until it gets to the actual equality check, and even then I didn't dig deep enough to figure out if it still gets on, whereas the `GetValue` overhead is much simpler, so do you think the reference-equality check here is recommended/redundant?
I'm not gonna do it in all properties, but there are those repetitive ones with a lot of overhead.

Comment: You save a few hops on the `SetValue` part, but you lose some on `GetValue` as well, so in the end there doesn't seem to be a lot of difference. You can try to benchmark both approaches to find out the exact performance difference.

Comment: I didn't figure out if using `SetValue` is guaranteed to check before reassigning an equal value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this part of the `BindableObject` class: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs#L554

It is checking if the value is the same before triggering the OnPropertyChanging event (line 554), and before setting the context value (line 563):

```
if (!same || raiseOnEqual)
{
    context.Value = value;
}
```

According to performance, I've just benchmarked it with constant changing values for the property. When checking the value like you suggest, costs about 56 ticks on average, while if you don't it is about 54 ticks on average (basic benchmark, not very scientific).

So the conclusion is, there is not much use for checking equality yourself in `BindableProperties` like these.

Comment: When is actually changing even equal? My question wasn't really on performance, it was if the `propertyChanged` delegate argument (in `BindableProperty.Create`) will ever be called with its `oldValue` and `newValue` equal.

Comment: Using one approach or the other is often a choice of performance, that's why I included a performance part in the answer. The `propertyChanged` delegate will only be called if the property actually is different (see line 595 of the referenced class). PS: the `raiseOnEqual` flag is an internal flag.